# I am just curious about the things written on Graphics

Tags: kernel, graphics, display, amd-graphics, gallium

I am new to ubuntu and on Detail about the computer in Graphics section "Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-40-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)" is written. what all these letter meant about my computer graphics?

Comment: Which ones precisely?? This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_5000_Series. AMD is the manufacturer, CEDAR is the particular card, DRM is the driver - Direct Rendering Manager, LLVM is an intermediate machine language used for graphics commands, IIRC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gallium = open source graphics driver

AMD = graphics card manufacture - Advanced Micro Devices Inc.

CEDAR = code name of card - Radeon HD5000 series

DRM = Direct Render Manager

4.10.0-40-generic = your linux kernel version

LLVM = Low Level Virtual Machine (LLVM) is a compiler infrastructure, written in C++, which is designed for compile-time, link-time, run-time, and "idle-time" optimization of programs written in arbitrary programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

- Gallium is essentially an API for writing graphics drivers in a largely device-agnostic fashion. It provides several objects which encapsulate the core services of graphics hardware in a straightforward manner.
- AMD Cedar GPU is the name of a series of Graphics Processing Units (GPUs) that was launched by AMD in 2010. Two important things to know about this GPU are the launch date (2010) and the processor lithography (40nm). By comparison the latest Intel and AMD CPUs have 14nm processor lithography.
- Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) is a subsystem of the Linux kernel, interfaces with the GPUs of modern video cards. DRM exposes an API that user-space programs can use to send commands and data to the GPU, and to perform operations such as configuring the mode setting of the display.<sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager)</sup>
- 4.10.0-40-generic is the version of the Linux kernel that is currently being used as the default kernel that is selected automatically when Ubuntu is booted.
- The Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM) is a collection of libraries and
  tools that make it easy to build compilers, optimizers, Just-In-Time
  code generators, and many other compiler-related programs.